# Negative and positive in same direction in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Helo,

It's possible showing the negative and positive series in the same diretion using highchart?

Like this:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DneLX.png)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, But you need to fudge it. Make the label show negative, but use absolute value(always positive) of the figure.

After your comment and link to the code, I was able to find a solution that I think will work for you.

```js
//tooltip function
function format_tt(inp) {
  index = this.point.index;


  var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
  var point = this.point;

  s += '<br/><span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>: ' + point.series.name + ': ' + tdata[index];

  return s;
}

//Data
tdata = [20, -20];
//Rework the data to use only the positive values, but only for our graph. Wherever we need the true values, we reference tdata.
data = tdata.map(function(_) {
  return Math.abs(_);
});
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    legend: {
      align: "center",
      labelFormatter: function() {
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.yData.length; i++) {
          count += this.yData[i]; //change this to tdata[i] to get the true value;
        }

        return this.name + ' (' + count + ')';
      },
      y: 3
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Column chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Receitas', 'Despesas']
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Receitas e despesas',
      data: data //Our data, AFTER the conversion
    }],
    tooltip: {
      formatter: format_tt //our tooltip function.
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zb2edyLe/3/

tdata is now where you'd put your data. Not the original place, Please review the comments within the code as that explains what I've done.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the total of legend was not correct.